# How to implicitly pass all arguments down the stack?

Tags: r

Take the following code:

```r
f2 <- function(...) {
  print(list(...))
}

f1 <- function(x, y = 1, ...) {
  z <- 20
  f2(x, y, ...)
}

f1(5, k = 6)
```

If I change the arguments to `f1`, and I still want to pass all those arguments to `f2`, I would need to change the call to `f2`. Is it possible to write the call to `f2` so that it does not name `x` and `y` explicitly? Something like the following (non-working code):

```r
f1 <- function(x, y = 1, ...) {
  z <- 20
  do.call(f2, formals())
}
```

I can use `environment()`, but then I need to take care that I call it at the very beginning:

```
f1 <- function(x, y = 1, ...) {
  argv <- c(as.list(environment()), ...)
  z <- 20
  do.call(f2, argv)
}
```

Is there maybe a simpler, more direct way?

Comment: Why not just have `f1 <- function(...) {z <- 20; f2(...)}`?

Comment: @AllanCameron The example is simplified. In my actual case, `f1` makes use of its named arguments, so I can't define it as `function(...)`.

Comment: fair enough. See my actual answer for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you wanted the variable `z` added to the call, but in either case you can achieve what you are looking for using `match.call`. You can simply swap in the quoted name of `f2` as the first element in the matched call, and if you wish to add the missing defaults from the `f1` formals, you can find them in `formals()` and write any missing ones into the matched call. Finally, you evaluate this call.

```r
f1 <- function(x, y = 1, ...) {

  mc   <- match.call()
  form <- names(formals())[!names(formals()) %in% names(mc)]
  form <- form[form != "..."]
  mc[[1]]  <- quote(f2)
  mc[form] <- formals()[form]
  mc$z <- 20
  eval(mc)
}

f2 <- function(...) {
  print(list(...))
}

f1(5, k = 6)
#> $x
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $k
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $z
#> [1] 20
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I was indeed not explicit about it, but I precisely didn't want `z` added to the call. Otherwise my original approach with `environment()` would have worked fine. I didn't know about `match.call`. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrei z can be removed very easily. Hope this approach works out for you

Comment: Still choosing :) The disadvantage of `environment` is that the code gets split—the `environment` needs to go at the top of the function to avoid extra captures—and I somewhat dislike that. The disadvantage of `match.call` is that the parameters are left unevaluated, i.e. `f1(5, k = g(1))` will give `$k = g(1)`. I don't yet know if it matters for my particular case.